# Azure DevOps REST API swagger url

Tags: azure-devops, swagger, azure-devops-rest-api

Does Azure DevOps REST API has swagger url?

I would like to be able to generate wrapper code in C# or Powershell around it, but cannot find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid there is not swagger url for azure devops api. [Azure DevOps Services .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.webapi.workitemtrackinghttpclient?view=azure-devops-dotnet) is available to integrate with C#.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops) is an example showing how to use Azure DevOps Services .NET SDK.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#assemble-the-request) is an example showing how to call Restful api via httpclient.

For powershell You can refer to below example:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<...>/MyconsoleApp/_apis/wiki/wikis/MyconsoleApp.wiki/pages?path=/SamplePage123&api-version=5.0"
$connectionToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$base64AuthInfo= System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get
```

Comment: I think this is alittle silly. If I just want to poke the API in postman for example, and not build a client to do it or use Powershell?

Answer (score 15):

OpenAPI 2.0 definitions for Azure DevOps Services REST APIs are available in this repository:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [AzurePipelinesPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS) on the PSGallery it is a PowerShell module that wraps the api.

If you would prefer to write your own wrapper you can check out the [rest api documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the available Swagger 2.0 documents for the AzDOS REST API at GitHub has been imported to [SwaggerHub](https://app.swaggerhub.com/search?query=azure+devops&sort=BEST_MATCH&order=DESC). You will be required to register an account.